# How can I enable /dev/spidev0,0 on a rock64 system?

Tags: python, arm, linux-device-driver, spi

Context: I am trying to make the python demo code of Waveshare ePaper (like https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/E-Paper_Driver_HAT) work with Rock64.

I already used the different python lib (with RPi.GPIO-PineA64) and adjusted the pinout.

```
Current os (uname -a) is Linux rock64 4.4.126-rockchip-ayufan-239 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Current Error is:
File "/root/test-code/python/epdif.py", line 43, in 
SPI = spidev.SpiDev(0, 0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think it might be just a command similar to
"enable_dtoverlay i2c0 i2c@ff150000 okay" but I have not figured out what the magic words are or what I need to change.

I looked at the docs for device trees, but thats beyond my understanding what I need to do.

Similar unanswered Questions are:

1. https://forum.armbian.com/topic/5951-activate-spidev-on-the-rock64/
2. https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5409
   [...]

Not understood to the point that I can act on it:

1. https://github.com/ayufan-rock64/linux-build/blob/master/recipes/additional-devices.md#use-additional-devices

Similar Questions with an answer that does not work (anymore) or are beyond my skills are:

1. https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5682 (didn't work)
2. https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=4869 (modprobe did not do the trick for me)
3. https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5473 (no clue if its related)
4. https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=1297&page=5 (other distro, right?)

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not committed to using Ayufan's OS images, I would suggest trying out [Armbian Xenial](https://www.armbian.com/rock64/) (based on Ubuntu 16.04) and then you may apply the solution from [point 4](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=1297&page=5) in your post, as the approach suggested by user "martinayotte" in that thread has received positive feedback and it also provides a way to test if the newly enabled SPI device works.

Personally, I have been running Armbian Xenial  on my 4GB Rock64 and have no complains so far, apart from [this](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5137), but I think it's a more general issue as opposed to a Armbian one.

Also, I stumbled onto [this post](http://synfare.com/599N105E/hwdocs/pine64/spidev.html) which provides an solution for a Pine64 board, not the Rock64, but maybe you can try to adapt it.

Comment: Wrap-Up: In the only reply within a month to this problem. But it requires change of distro for a rather complicated system (elastic search, tikka, vpn, scripts, etc.). That, of course, creates other problems and itself isn't helping with a solution. 

For now, am I wrong to consider spidev and using 08/15 displays on rock64 non-functional? I'm sorry that we can't provide a secure display for our journalists to verify against, but it seems it is beyond reach.

Answer (score -2):

I think I have the answer to your question. Even I faced the same issue so I tried all the solutions provided in the links you shared, including the armbian ones.

I booted into armbian using eMMC and did the steps as mentioned by @dontpostalot in [this link](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5473) on modifying the device tree overlay. As of now, I have spidev showing in my /dev folder. I'm yet to interface a device using it.

The steps are the same for Ubuntu as well as armbian except for the fact that you will have to identify the right `.dtb` that's synonymous to your board in your `/boot` folder.